# Serializing an object with restsharp and passing it to WebApi not serializing list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json.net, restsharp

I have a a view model that looks like.

```
public class StoreItemViewModel
{
    public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
    public List<Guid> StoreIds { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    //[Required]
    //[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public int ItemTypeId { get; set; }


}
```

I have a small helper that using is using RestSharp.

```
public static IRestResponse Create<T>(object objectToUpdate, string apiEndPoint) where T : new()
    {
        var client = new RestClient(CreateBaseUrl(null))
        {
            Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("user", "Password1")
        };

        var request = new RestRequest(apiEndPoint, Method.POST);
        //request.JsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
       // {RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json};
        request.AddObject(objectToUpdate);
       // clientJsonSerializer = new YourCustomSerializer();
        var response = client.Execute<T>(request);
        return response;
    }
```

When debugging the controller within my api

```
 [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Create([FromBody]StoreItemViewModel myProduct)
    {
        //check fields are valid
     .........
     }
```

myProducts products are all populated apart from the  public List StoreIds it always is returning a single reward with an empty Guid. Even if I have added 2 or more StoreIds

I assume this is because I am doing something wrong with my Create helper within my application.

Can anyone help with this its causing a major headache.

The raw data sent to the webapi is looking like

```
ItemId=f6dbd244-e840-47e1-9d09-53cc64cd87e6&ItemTypeId=6&Description=blabla&StoreIds=d0f36ef4-28be-4d16-a2e8-37030004174a&StoreIds=f6dbd244-e840-47e1-9d09-53cc64cd87e6&StoreId=d0f36ef4-28be-4d16-a2e8-37030004174a
```

Comment: could you share how the raw json request looks like?

Comment: @KiranChalla sorry how do I get that using the restsharp bits?

Comment: you could use Fiddler, which is a httpproxy, to capture the requests/responses.

Comment: haha I didnt know I could use fiddler for the serverside stuff. I always thought it was just for clientside stuff. Thanks for the tip :) I just updated the post with the raw json

Comment: So I have gotten as far as seeing that the StoreIds is not set properly when the data is serialized. I tried testing with the json.net library and it works fine. If I need to use the json.net library I am happy to do that I just dont know how to pass the json.net serlialized object to the api

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I managed to get this working. I don't think its the correct way but it works.

```
 public static IRestResponse Create<T>(object objectToUpdate, string apiEndPoint) where T : new()
    {
        var client = new RestClient(CreateBaseUrl(null))
        {
            Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("user", "Password1")
        };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToUpdate);
        var request = new RestRequest(apiEndPoint, Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("text/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        var response = client.Execute<T>(request);
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. However, I did have to use "application/json" rather than "text/json". Thanks!

Comment: Hey did you ever find a official way to do this?

Answer (score 23):

RestSharp now has a more streamlined way to add an object to the RestRequest Body with Json Serialization:

```
public static IRestResponse Create<T>(object objectToUpdate, string apiEndPoint) where T : new()
{
    var client = new RestClient(CreateBaseUrl(null))
    {
        Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("user", "Password1")
    };
    var request = new RestRequest(apiEndPoint, Method.POST);
    request.AddJsonBody(objectToUpdate); // HERE
    var response = client.Execute<T>(request);
    return response;
}
```

This was found in RestSharp 105.0.1.0

Answer (score 14):

I struggled with the same problem and came up a working solution.

1. Be sure to set the request format to JSON:

   request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
2. Use AddBody, rather than AddObject:

   request.AddBody(zNewSessionUsage);

So your code would be something like this:

```
public static IRestResponse Create<T>(object objectToUpdate, string apiEndPoint) where T : new()
{
    var client = new RestClient(CreateBaseUrl(null))
    {
        Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("user", "Password1")
    };

    var request = new RestRequest(apiEndPoint, Method.POST);
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddBody(objectToUpdate);
    var response = client.Execute<T>(request);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: And it appears .RequestFormat must be listed before .AddBody as per the example above otherwise it'll still default to XML Serialization.