# Can RestSharp send a List<string> in a POST request?

Tags: json, serialization, restsharp

I am trying to get [RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp) to work with a restful service that I have. Everything seems to be working fine, except when my object being passed via `POST` contains a list (in this particular case a list of `string`).

My object:

```
public class TestObj
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public List<string> Children{get;set;}
}
```

When this gets sent to the server  the `Children` property gets sent as a string with the contents `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] ``.

This is how I am sending the object:

```
var client = new RestClient();
var request = new RestRequest("http://localhost", Method.PUT);

var test = new TestObj {Name = "Fred", Children = new List<string> {"Arthur", "Betty"}};
request.AddObject(test);
client.Execute<TestObj>(request);
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in RestSharp? (If it makes a difference, I am using JSON, not XML.)

Answer (score 9):

It depends on what server you're hitting, but if you're hitting an ASP.NET Web API controller (and probably other server-side technologies), it'll work if you add each item in the collection in a loop:

```
foreach (var child in test.Children) 
    request.AddParameter("children", x));
```

Comment: I think this should be the top answer. There's no one proper way to get around this, and I personally think RestSharp should essentially employ this by default considering how prevalent IEnumerables are in web frameworks. Compared to other solutions I've seen on this post and on similar posts this solution can easily be encapsulated and relies on no external library (that likely introduces some overhead on each node in the collection).

Answer (score 3):

Use **AddJsonBody**

```
var client = new RestClient();
var request = new RestRequest("http://localhost", Method.PUT);
request.AddJsonBody(new TestObj {
     Name = "Fred", 
     Children = new List<string> {"Arthur", "Betty"}
});
client.Execute(request);
```

Api Side

```
[AcceptVerbs("PUT")]
string Portefeuille(TestObj obj)
{
    return String.Format("Sup' {0}, you have {1} nice children", 
        obj.Name, obj.Children.Count());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Koranger - would you know how the object would look in params - so it can be accessed in the server controller?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with a list of Guids. My post would work but the list would never have the correct data. I hacked it abit and used the json.net to serialize the object

[Issue I had on another stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260465/serializing-an-object-with-restsharp-and-passing-it-to-webapi-not-serializing-li)

I know this isn't perfect but does the trick

Comment: I use JSON strings when dealing with IEnumerables in MVC viewmodels for what it's worth, so I don't think this is a bad solution at all.