# How to authenticate with RestSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp, restful-authentication

I would like to authenticate me on spreadshirt but I get an internal server error as result.

Im new to Rest API..

So here is the documentation: https://developer.spreadshirt.net/display/API/Security+Resources

and my Code:

```
        var client = new RestClient("https://api.spreadshirt.net/api/v1");

        var request = new RestRequest("sessions", Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("username", "foo");
        request.AddParameter("password", "bar");
        var test = client.Execute(request);
```

EDIT:

Got it

My Login Class

```
[SerializeAs(Name ="login")]
public class Login
{
    private string user;
    private string pw;


    [SerializeAs(Name ="username")]
    public string username
    {
        get
        {
            return "foo";
        }
        set
        {
            this.user = value;
        }
    }
    [SerializeAs(Name ="password")]
    public string password
    {
        get { return "bar"; }
        set { this.pw = value; }
    }
}
```

On Button Click

```
var login = new Login();
        var request = new RestRequest("sessions/", Method.POST);

        var client = new RestClient("https://api.spreadshirt.net/api/v1/");

        request.XmlSerializer = new RestSharp.Serializers.XmlSerializer();
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;

        request.AddXmlBody(login, "http://api.spreadshirt.net");

        var response = client.Execute(request);
        MessageBox.Show(response.StatusCode.ToString());
```

Comment: It's a REST API but requests must be in XML. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34527935/building-xml-request-with-restsharp

Comment: thanks, could you tell me whats wrong with it now?

Comment: I would just try it and see if it works. If not, then post a specific error here. I can't say either way just by looking at the code.

Comment: it throws me the same internal server error. Im not sure if im doing it right with my Login class or if I miss something to pass

Comment: Can you do the debug and share the request value?. Some of the request also cause an internal server error problem

Comment: Im already solved that problem, see my edit :)